# Replace third line of nth file with nth line of a single file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, awk, sed

Say I have hundreds of `*.xml` in `/train/xml/`, in the following format

```
# this is the content of /train/xml/RIGHT_NAME.xml
<annotation>
    <path>/train/img/WRONG_NAME.jpg</path>    # this is the WRONG_NAME
</annotation>
```

The file name **WRONG_NAME** in `<path>...</path>` should match that of the `.xml` file, so that it looks like this:

```
# this is the content of /train/xml/RIGHT_NAME.xml
<annotation>
    <path>/train/img/RIGHT_NAME.jpg</path>    # this is the **RIGHT_NAME**
</annotation>
```

One solution I can think of is to:

##### 1. export all file names into a text file:

```
ls -1 *.xml > filenames.txt
```

which generates a file with the content:

```
RIGHT_NAME_0.xml
RIGHT_NAME_1.xml
...
```

##### 2. then edit `filenames.txt`, so that it becomes:

```xml
# tab at beginning of each line
    <path>/train/img/RIGHT_NAME_0.jpg</path>
    <path>/train/img/RIGHT_NAME_1.jpg</path>
    ...
```

##### 3. Then, replace the third line of `n`th `.xml` file with the `n`th line from `filenames.txt`.

Thus the question title.

I've hammered around with `sed`and `awk` but had no success. How should I do it (on a **EDIT: MacOS** machine)? Also, is there a more elegant solution?

Thanks in advance for helping out!

---things I've tried (and didnt work out)---

```
# this replaces the fifth line with an empty string
for i in *.xml ; do perl -i.bak -pe 's/.*/$i/ if $.==5' RIGHT_NAME.xml ; done

# this apprehends contents of filenames.txt after third line
sed -i.bak -e '/\<path\>/r filenames.txt' RIGHT_NAME.xml

# also, trying to utilize the <path>...</path> pattern...
```

Comment: *I've hammered around with `sed` and `awk` but had no success.*. Can you share some specific examples of what you've tried? It would seem to me that if you setup a search for your files and match the name, you can then use `sed -i` to modify the file using the base of the matched name. The mashing into a single file is a less desirable approach.

Comment: hey that was quick! The closest I've got so far was: 
`sed -i.bak -e '/\<path\>/r filenames.txt' RIGHT_NAME.xml`
which apprehends contents of `filenames.txt` after third line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```
for xml in *.xml; do
    sed -E -i.bak '3s/([^/]*.jpg)/'"${xml/.xml/.jpg}/" "$xml"
done
```

Comment: trying on macOS wth `for xml in *.xml; do sed -E -i.bak '3s/([^/]*.jpg)/'"${xml/.xml/.jpg}/" "$f" ; done` returns `sed: : No such file or directory`

Comment: Oops . Fixed. My mistake. I added the .bak as well. (But your question was tagged Ubuntu, not Macos. The utility commands differ.)

Comment: May bad! I'm  running a headless ubuntu setup on my mac.. Edited.

Comment: @sch. No worries. The problem (I hope) was the incorrect `$f`. I'm on a cell phone so no way to test.

Comment: It'd be more efficient to `q`uit after line #3 because `sed` will keep reading a large file all the way to the end.  This would be faster:  `'3{s/([^/]*.jpg)/'"${xml/.xml/.jpg}/"';q}`

Comment: @agc: you have to read all the way to the end in order to copy the rest of the file.

Answer (score 1):

If `ed` is acceptable since it should be installed by default on a mac.

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in ./*.xml; do
  printf 'Processing %s\n' "$file"
  f=${file%.*}; f=${f#*./}
  printf '%s\n' H "g/<annotation>/;/<\/annotation>/\
    s|^\([[:blank:]]*<path>.*/\)[^.]*\(.*</path>\)|\1${f}\2|" %p Q |
  ed -s "$file" || break
done
```

---

- Will give desired results even if you have

  `/foo/bar/baz/more/train/img/WRONG_NAME.jpg`
- Will only edit/parse the string inside the `path` tag which is inside the `annotation` tag.
- Change `Q` to `w` if in-place editing is needed.
- Remove the `%p` to silence the output.

Caveat:
`ed` is not an xml editor/parser.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk (which you can easily install on MacOS if it's not already present on your system) for "inplace" editing, gensub() and the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,"(^\\s*<path>.*/).*([.][^.]+</path>)",a) {
    name = gensub("(.*/)?(.*)[.][^.]+$","\\2",1,FILENAME)
    $0 = a[1] name a[2]
}
{ print }
```

```
$ head *.xml
==> RIGHT_NAME_1.xml <==
# this is the content of /train/xml/RIGHT_NAME_1.xml
<annotation>
    <path>/train/img/WRONG_NAME.xml.jpg</path>
</annotation>

==> RIGHT_NAME_2.xml <==
# this is the content of /train/xml/RIGHT_NAME_2.xml
<annotation>
    <path>/train/img/WRONG_NAME.xml.jpg</path>
</annotation>
```

```
$ awk -i inplace -f tst.awk *.xml
```

```
$ head *.xml
==> RIGHT_NAME_1.xml <==
# this is the content of /train/xml/RIGHT_NAME_1.xml
<annotation>
    <path>/train/img/RIGHT_NAME_1.jpg</path>
</annotation>

==> RIGHT_NAME_2.xml <==
# this is the content of /train/xml/RIGHT_NAME_2.xml
<annotation>
    <path>/train/img/RIGHT_NAME_2.jpg</path>
</annotation>
```

Just call it as `awk -i inplace -f tst.awk /train/xml/*` on your system. Note that the above just replaces the name in the `<path>` tag content wherever it occurs on it's own line and so it will work whether that's the 3rd line in any given file or some other line. If you REALLY only want to do this for the 3rd line then just change `match(...` to `FNR==3 && match(...`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
parallel --dry sed -i '3s#[^/]*.jpg#{/.}.jpg#' {} ::: /train/xml/*.xml
```

In parallel the `{}` represents the file name and its path whereas the `{/.}` represents the filename less the path and its extension.

Once the output from the above solution has been checked the option `--dry` which is short form `--dry-run` can be removed.